# How to insert-or-replace an entity in Cosmos DB atomically?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

In Cosmos DB, I have a container to store a bunch of product types. All product types have unique `type`, we can use `type` as a unique identity for each product type.

Here is an example of product type:

```json
{
    "type": "type1",
    "introduction": "this is type 1",
    "size": 10
}
```

I have a process to insert-or-replace the product types. This process should be atomic and transactional, which means when there is no item with `type = "type3"` in container, and multiple process trying to insert `{ type": "type3", "introduction": "this is type 3" }` to the container, there should only be one item with `type = "type3"` after all processes finished.

So I use a stored procedure to do this insert-or-replace logic:

```js
function addOrUpdateEntity(entity) {
    var documentQuery = {
            'query': 'SELECT * FROM c where c.type = @param',
            'parameters': [{ 'name': '@param', 'value': entity.type }]
        };

    __.queryDocuments(__.getSelfLink(), documentQuery,
        function (err, items) {
            if (items.length === 0) {
                __.createDocument(__.getSelfLink(), entity, {}, function(err, item, options) {
                    if (err) { throw err; }
                })
            } else if (items.length === 1) {
                const oldEntity = items[0];
                const newEntity = Object.assign({}, oldEntity);
                newEntity.introduction = entity.introduction
                __.replaceDocument(oldEntity._self, newEntity, function (err) {
                    if (err) { throw err; }
                });
            }
        }
    );
}
```

But under concurrency process running scenario, I got two items with duplicate `type = "type3"`.

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript), the execution of stored procedure is transactional, then what is the reason of duplicate items all have `type = "type3"`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Optimistic Concurrency control](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control).

This would be the pseudo code, the actual code depends on the language of your choice and SDK you are using:

1. Perform a read to detect if it exists or not.
2. If it doesn't exist, attempt the Create.
3. If it does exist, capture the read response's ETag.
4. Update item and pass the ETag of the read to the replace operation through the `IfMatch` option.
5. If there was a concurrent update to the same document, you will get a failure with HTTP 412 status code.
6. You can repeat the process if you need to, to read again, get the latest ETag, send the Replace again (this is assuming you need to execute the Replace on this condition).

EDIT: To clarify, you execute these steps outside of a Stored procedure, they are just operations from the client.

Comment: Given an empty container, and two processes A and B both try to write same content. There might be a case both A and B see no existance in step 1 and proceed with step 2,  causing duplicate item creations?

Comment: Not possible. If both call Create and the identity of the document is the same (id + PK) then one of them will fail with HTTP 409. If they don't fail it means they are different documents (id and/or PK values are different).

Comment: Got it, correct id+PK and ETag based submit is enough to guarantee uniqueness. 
(Not sure should raise another question, and I want to digg deeper in my case)  What is the **transactional** means in terms of stored procedure. In my case, why can concurrency executions add duplicate items when the container is empty, seems all code path runs into `if (items.length === 0)` branch

Comment: Transactional means that if you execute 3 operations inside a SPROC (create A, create B, create C), if one of them fails (A succeeds, but B fails), then all of them are reverted (A is reverted). It's all or nothing in a single database transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about a concurrency or transactional issue; it's about unique key constraints (or lack of unique key constraint). The only unique constraint that exists by default is with `/id`.

If you add `/type` as a unique key constraint, then this would prevent, say, multiple documents with `type = "type1"`.

Just note that this constraint is within a partition (and you haven't mentioned your partition key).

Also, you'll need to re-create your container - pretty sure you can't add a unique key constraint post-creation.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys)

Comment: Actually I add an `partitionKey` property in each item, value is the same with `type`. And the partition key is set to `/partitionKey`. Is this a good idea to add `/type` as a unique key constraint, to achieve a global uniqueness in terms of `type` value?